# Search in multiple models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have many different models in Django and I want to search for a keyword in all of them.
For example, if you searched "blah", I want to show all of the products with "blah", all of the invoices with "blah", and finally all of the other models with "blah".

I can develop a view and search in all of the models separately, but it's not a good idea.

What is the best practice for this situation?

Comment: Are you using postgres as the database? if so read on `SearchVector`

Comment: Yes, I'm using Postgres. I saw it, Seems SearchVector is using for one model

Comment: I have an answer.  I'll post some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this situation a few times and one solution is to use model managers, and create distinct search methods for single and multi-word queries.  Take the following example models below: Each has its own custom Model Manager, with two separate query methods.  `search` will query single-word searches against all fields, while `search_and` will query each word in a list of search words, using the `reduce` function.  Both use `Q` objects to accomplish multi-field lookups.

```
from functools import reduce
from django.db.models import Q

class ProductQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(product_name__icontains=query) | 
                         Q(description__icontains=query) | 
                         Q(category__icontains=query))

            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup, active=True, released=True).distinct()
        return qs

    def search_and(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [(Q(product_name__icontains=word) |
                                                     Q(description__icontains=word) | 
                                                     Q(category__icontains=word)) for word in query])
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup, active=True, released=True).distinct()
        
        return qs
      

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def search(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)

    def search_and(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search_and(query=query)


class Product(models.Model):
    product_name        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description         = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, null=True)    
    category            = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORY)
   
    objects = ProductManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name


class ProfileQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    
    def search(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = (Q(full_name__icontains=query) | 
                         Q(job_title__icontains=query) | 
                         Q(function__icontains=query))

            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup, active=True, released=True).distinct()
        return qs

    def search_and(self, query=None):
        qs = self
        if query is not None:
            or_lookup = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [(Q(full_name__icontains=word) |
                                                     Q(job_title__icontains=word) | 
                                                     Q(function__icontains=word)) for word in query])
            qs = qs.filter(or_lookup, active=True, released=True).distinct()
        
        return qs
      

class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProfileQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def search(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search(query=query)

    def search_and(self, query=None):
        return self.get_queryset().search_and(query=query)


class Profile(models.Model):
    full_name           = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    job_title           = models.CharField(max_length=240, blank=True, null=True)    
    function            = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=FUNCTION)
   
    objects = ProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

Now to use these in a search view, which you can point at as many model managers as you like, which can query as many fields as you like.  Using the example models above, here's a sample view, below.  It passes the search term or terms to the appropriate model manager method, based on the count of terms (either 1 or more than 1).

```
def application_search(request):
    data = dict()
    
    if 'query' in request.GET: 
        query_list = request.GET.get("query", None).split()
        if query_list:
            try:
                if len(query_list) > 1:
                    products = Product.objects.search_and(query=query_list)
                    profiles = Profile.objects.search_and(query=query_list)
                else:
                    products = Product.objects.search(query=query_list[0])
                    profiles = Profile.objects.search(query=query_list[0])
            except:
                # Throw exception or log error here 
            try:
                queryset_chain = chain(products, profiles) # combines querysets into one
                results = sorted(queryset_chain, key=lambda instance: instance.id, reverse=True) #sorts results by ID
            except:
                results = None        

        data['results'] = render_to_string('pages/my_search_result_page.html', {'results': results})

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

The `query` in this view is actually being passed to the backend via AJAX, but you may do it differently based on your needs and template design.